# Not Able to Set Cookie using NodeJs in Browser Application tab even its coming in response

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am in a weird situation where cookie is not getting set in browser and in response its showing in browser

[image]

Response Screenshot from Network Tab
[image]

React Application Running on Domain - https://2367cc15b.eu.ngrok.io

Node Js Running On Domain - https://e17b14c2835b.ngrok.io

Code to set cookie

```
res.cookie('holofyKey', holofyKey, { httpOnly: true, domain: '.ngrok.io', expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)) });
```

I am using `app.use(cookieParser());` in my middleware.

Is there something i am missing ?

PS - I tried with removing httpOnly and domain name from options still no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 2 days trying every possible solution this finally worked for me

This is how you need to call the api from which you want to set the cookie.

```
const postHelper = async (url, body) => {
  return await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "applicaiton/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: body && JSON.stringify(body),
    withCredentials: true, // should be there
    credentials: 'include' // should be there
  });
};
```

After adding this you will get CORS error so please add this line of code in your server

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
```

And finally

```
res.cookie('cookieKey', cookieKey, { expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)), secure: true  });
```

PS - This solution will work in case of Cross domain and same domain but in case of cross domain most browsers will not allow you to set cookie until user agree.